# Score not the same on Stack Overflow app and in browser

Tags: bug, android-app, tag-score, browser-support

This is a mysterious problem I've had for a while:

I've got the Stack Overflow app and it gives me a score on one of my tags (Python):

[image]

However when I look on my browser (Chrome at the same time) it displays this:

[image]

Clearly one of these is wrong because my score can't be both 16 and 17 and there was definitely no change when I did these screenshots.

Comment: Does it ever become the same (blame caching) or always different ?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov  Always different.  Every day.  Every time I look at it I automatically subtract 1.  The SO app is always ahead by 1.

Comment: I can come back in a week and tell you it's ahead by 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app counts your combined question and answer score and one of your [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46698837/can-i-import-modules-from-thread-in-python) that you tagged with [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) has a score of one, hence the app's +1.

Your question is really a cross-site duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212299/tag-score-calculation-wrong-in-android-app)

Comment: So is my score total score actually 17 then? How do I find that out on my browser?

Comment: Yeah indeed it looks like it is.

Comment: No, for getting the badge, only answers count.

Comment: Ok thanks very much.  It's definitely a duplicate